# Delete identical files from one folder in bash (ubuntu 20.4)

Tags: 14.04

I need to write a Bash Script program.
The program gets a source folder d1 and a target folder d2 likr this: d1@d2.
Then - she go through the files in the 2 folders, and if there are identical files, delete them from folder d1.
It is important to note that I am new to the field, and I am limited in advanced methods.
This is the code I just wrote, and I do not know how to proceed.

```
    echo -n "Enter parameters in the format "
    read directory

x=$(echo $directory | cut -d"@" -f1)
y=$(echo $directory | cut -d"@" -f2)


while [ $f1 -ne $f2 ]
do
    if [ $x -ne $y ]
    then
    $x == $y
    
    continue

fi
done
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned an OS or release, but you've tagged an off-topic EOL/ESM release.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   What OS & release are you using?

Comment: Hi - Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Why tag 14.04 if you're using 20.04?  (Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, 14.04 LTS reached EOL in 2019-April, and 14.04 ESM is supported elsewhere being off-topic here). Please try and correct your tag (you can edit your own question).

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the parsing of your format by setting `IFS` to your chosen delimiter this will make `read` split words at `@` instead of space. Using *globbing* `"$b"/*` in a for-loop will iterate file/dir objects in the source directory. `${d##*/}` removes the source path from the file object, we can then create a new target object `$c/$e`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=@ \
read -r -p "Enter parameters in the format source@target: " b c

for d in "$b"/*; do
    e="${d##*/}"
    if [[ -f "$c/$e" ]]; then
        echo rm -- "$c/$e"
    fi
done
```